# actualSolve raise PulpSolverError("CPLEX_PY: Not Available")

Tags: python, cplex, pulp

I am trying to run an optimization program using pulp and cplex I have installed cplex studio. I have change the path name as instructed

```
Name: Path
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\_internal
```

but I am still receiving the error CPLEX_PY: Not Available.
I was wondering if anyone else was able to solve this problem or what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought you were trying to use the CPLEX_CMD solver, but I see that you want to use CPLEX_PY instead. The former relies on the CPLEX interactive (`cplex.exe`) being in your `PATH` environment variable. The later requires that you either install the CPLEX Python API or include it in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Please see the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html) for setting up the CPLEX Python API.

Based on what you have in your question, you could run `setup.py` like so:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64"
python setup.py install
```

Or, you could add the following to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64
```

See how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

In any case, you need to make sure that you can do the following from the python prompt:

```
>>> import cplex
```

Also, make sure you are using a 64-bit python.

Comment: I have added the PYTHONPATH, but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. When trying to import cplex

Comment: Think the 64 bit might be my problem

Comment: Ok so when I switched back to Python2 it says cplex isn't compatible with python2 and when i download python3 i can only download the 32-bit

Comment: You need to make sure that you install the correct cplex package for the version of python you are using. Under "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python" you will see a directory for 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7. The versions supported are different depending on the version of CPLEX you are working with, but it looks like you are using CPLEX 12.9 so this should be correct in your case.